# Is there a way to enable some kind of autoupdate in the appcenter updates?

Tags: updates, appcenter

Is there a way to enable some kind of autoupdate in the appcenter updates?
I'm using Elementary OS Hera 5.1.6

Answer (score 0):

AppCenter does not upgrade any packages without you asking it to.
When you boot, appcenter perform an "update" of the package cache in the background. This is the equivalent of `sudo apt update`. This doesn't modify any packages, it simply contacts the software repositories to see if any newer packages are available and you will get a notification if any updates are available. After this, you can choose whether to update or not.

Read more: [Appcenter Auto update](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/9unxae/appcenter_auto_update/)